# Robot Framework: All subsequent tests fail after one test fails

Tags: ssh, automated-tests, robotframework

Once one of my robot test fail, all further tests fail, I can't seem to find out why this happens.

I just execute a simple nslookup on my device and check if the output contains the word 'Name:'

Example:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SSHLibrary


Suite Setup            Open Connection And Log In
Suite Teardown         Close All Connections

*** Variables ***
${HOST}        localhost
${LOGIN}       testUser
${PASSWORD}    testUser

*** Keywords ***
Open Connection And Log In
    Open Connection     ${HOST}
    Login               ${LOGIN}        ${PASSWORD}


*** Test Cases ***
resolve dns domain on google:
  Write   nslookup qsdf.ft 8.8.4.4
  ${output}=   Read   delay=0.5s
  Should Contain  ${output}  Name:


resolve dns domain google.com:
  Write  nslookup google.com 8.8.4.4
  ${output}=  Read   delay=0.5s
  Should Contain  ${output}  Name:
```

The first test should fail and the second should pass.

It seems like the first test is stil waiting for its output while the other tests continue

my output on both tests:

```
'' does not contain 'Name:'
```

Comment: What happens if you use the keyword `Read Until` in the second case instead of `Read`?

Comment: No luck here, still the same errors